# How to mount a 2x4 to a cargo van wall without drilling?

Tags: modification, van

Need to attach a piece of a 2x4 to a cargo van wall, but don't want to use self-drilling screws, everyone on the web recommends because I don't want to drill the walls. There's already plenty of existing factory holes in wall "beams". Is there a way to somehow put bolts in those existing holes, fix them in place, then drill a hole in the 2x4 and hold it with a nut?

[image]

Comment: Why are you resistant to self tapping screws? Afraid they will not hold?

Comment: Yes, not sure they will hold. But also, don't want to bother with figuring out proper length and if I get it wrong, I could puncture the outer shell.

Comment: Length should be easy to calculate but I understand your concern.

Answer (score 5):

There is a product "rivnut" that you can put in the hole, do up, and it locks itself into place... Like a rivet, but it has a thread and is thicker / larger.

Then you can just "bolt through" - make sure that the bolt does not push on the outer skin when it is done up though !

There are many versions, this type may be interesting for you:
[image]

Found here : https://www.rivetsonline.com/rivet-nuts-threaded-inserts-c-182.html

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen those. Wish THD and Lowe's sold them so there's no need to wait and easier to return what's left.